# typescript map object return type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I run into some behavior that seems a bit weird to me.

In the following example, I have two functions that take an object as an input and return an object with the same keys but different values. When using `useForm1` I get the expected result. I can access the property keys of the input object and it also has the correct value (`Field`).

However when using `useForm2`, (which uses `Form<T>` instead of the inlined `{ [P in keyof T]: Field }` and at first look seems to actually be the same), I also get an object that has the keys of the input object, unfortunately, the values are not of type `Field` but rather  plain object (aka `{}` without any properties.).

Can anybody please explain why those two methods produce different results and how I could adjust the definitions for `useForm2`?

```
type FormConfig<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: {
    required?: boolean;
    validator?: (input: string) => void | Promise<void>;
    type: string;
  }
};

type Field = {
  required?: boolean;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  value: string;
};

type Form<T> = { [P in keyof T]: Field };

export const useForm1 = <T extends Object>(
  config: FormConfig<T>
): { [P in keyof T]: Field } => {
  // do some logic
};

export const useForm2 = <T extends Object>(config: FormConfig<T>): Form<T> => {
  // do some logic
};

const test1 = useForm1({
  login: {
    type: "text"
  }
});

const test2 = useForm2({
  login: {
    type: "text"
  }
});
```

Comment: My guess: `<T extends Object>(config: FormConfig<T>): Form<T>` just extends `{}` and also then just can return: `Form<{}>`. Whereas: `<T extends Object>(config: FormConfig<T>): { [P in keyof T]: Field }` you explicitly set the return value to `{ [P in keyof T]: Field }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object` is a very generic type and should almost never be used in TypeScript. In this case you expect to have a key-value map as an input and returned processed one, so this is the type you should specify in all constraints:

```js
type Form<T extends Record<string, any>> = { [P in keyof T]: Field };

export const useForm1 = <T extends Record<string, any>>(
  config: FormConfig<T>
): { [P in keyof T]: Field } => {
  // do some logic
  return null as any
};

export const useForm2 = <T extends Record<string, any>>(config: FormConfig<T>): Form<T> => {
  // do some logic
};

test2.login.required // works
```